# Replace column value in panda dataframe based on another colum value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following panda dataframe:

```
    Material    Min_lot      Reorder
0   E01            1            0
1   E02            1            -1
2   E03            1            10
3   E04            1            1
4   E05            5            0
5   E06            5            -1
6   E07            5            10
7   E08            5            5
8   E09            5            3
```

I want to create a new column or replace the existing Reorder based on the following rules

```
reorder <0 replace reorder with 0
reorder >= Min_lot -> do not change reorder
reorder < Min_lot  -> replace reorderwith Min_lot value
```

as an example the output is:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't the 0 become 1 or 5 is you first condition ≤ 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Reorder'] = (df['Reorder'].clip(df['Min_lot'])
                 .mask(df['Reorder'].lt(0), 0)
                )
```

Output:

```
  Material  Min_lot  Reorder
0      E01        1        1
1      E02        1        0
2      E03        1       10
3      E04        1        1
4      E05        5        5
5      E06        5        0
6      E07        5       10
7      E08        5        5
8      E09        5        5
```

Given your output it looks like the masking condition should be <= 0:

```
df['Reorder'] = (df['Reorder'].clip(df['Min_lot'])
                 .mask(df['Reorder'].le(0), 0)
                )
```

Output:

```
  Material  Min_lot  Reorder
0      E01        1        0
1      E02        1        0
2      E03        1       10
3      E04        1        1
4      E05        5        0
5      E06        5        0
6      E07        5       10
7      E08        5        5
8      E09        5        5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Reorder'] = df[['Min_lot', 'Reorder']].max(axis = 1) * (df['Reorder'] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you all have the conditions laid out, all you have to do is do them in order:

```
df['New_Reorder'] = df['Reorder']
m = df['Reorder'].lt(df['Min_lot'])
df.loc[m, 'New_Reorder'] = df.loc[m, 'Min_lot']
df.loc[df['Reorder'].le(0), 'New_Reorder'] = 0

print(df)

  Material  Min_lot  Reorder  New_Reorder
0      E01        1        0            0
1      E02        1       -1            0
2      E03        1       10           10
3      E04        1        1            1
4      E05        5        0            0
5      E06        5       -1            0
6      E07        5       10           10
7      E08        5        5            5
8      E09        5        3            5
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use np.where function which is same like Excel's nested if formula.
I applied the formula in the order which you written.

(

df['New_Reorder']=np.where(df.Reorder<0,0,
np.where(DF.Reorder < df.Min_lot,ff.Min_lot,df.Reorder))

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply() method:

```
df['New_Reorder'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(0, row['Min_lot']) if row['Reorder'] < row['Min_lot'] else row['Reorder'], axis=1)
```